# How to find the average of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Below is my code. I figured out how to find the average by copying someones code, which I had previously written by myself. The reason why my code didn't work was because of the following:

```
private int[ ] array;

public Arraylab(int[] Val)
{
   array = Val;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how my array which is given the name numArray even needed the code above. The array name isn't anywhere in the code above but yet it is needed so the code could run fine. Where the word "array" is in the code I had previously written "numArray" and it didn't work even though it looked like it was correct and should.

```
class Arraylab {

    private int[ ] array;

        public Arraylab(int[] Val)
        {
           array = Val;
        }

        public double Average()
        {
           double total = 0;
           for (int val : array)
           {
              total  = total + val;
           }
           return total / array.length;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] numArray =  {10,6,3,2,6};
            Arraylab obj = new Arraylab(numArray);
            System.out.println(obj.Average());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up object orientation and static method calling and that's why you are running into issues.

This line is making a new instance of your class `Arraylab obj = new Arraylab(numArray);` that is not the same instance as the one your main method is in, and that is why you need to initialise the `array` using the `public Arraylab(int[] Val)` method.

The simple solution would be to make the `Average` method `static` and pass your array directly to it:

```
class Arraylab {
    //We can return the average value from this method if we pass an int[] array into the method
    //This method also needs the static keyword so that we can call it directly
    public static double Average(int[] array)
    {
       double total = 0;
       for (int val : array)
       {
          total  = total + val;
       }
       return total / array.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create the array
        int[] numArray =  {10,6,3,2,6};
        //Pass the numArray into the Average method and store the returned result
        double result = Average(numArray);
        //Print the result
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#15427

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with java 8 or greater, you can use Streams.

First of all, create a Stream from the array with [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)) that'll return an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) which has the function [IntStream.average](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average()).

The last method will return an [OptionalDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) and as the docmuntation says. [OptionalDouble.orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElse(double)) returns the value if present otherwise returns a custom value (NaN for example).

The code it's pretty simple

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 56, 84, -2, 2};
        double average;
        average = Arrays.stream(numbers).average().orElse(Double.NaN);

        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream solution. If an average was computed, print it, else if not computed, display informative message of your choice.

```
int[] numArray =  {10,6,3,2,6};
OptionalDouble opd = Arrays.stream(numArray).average();
opd.ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, 
        ()->System.out.println("Empty Array"));
```

prints

```
5.4
```